# msgsnd: Invalid argument

Tags: c, multithreading, message-queue

I receive msgsnd: Invalid argument error while using my program. Another thing i noted is that error do 
not occur if the file size is medium while it occurs when file size is slightly more. Is is due to memory overflow? If yes then what is the solution.
Regards,
Bhavin.

Comment: To be more specific file size for which program succeeded was 152K and 75K and file sizes for which it gives msgsnd: Invalid argument error are  336K, 404K, 396K.

Answer (score 2):

`msgsnd()` returns `EINVAL` if the `msgsz` parameter is greater than `MSGMAX` (which is usually quite a small value, like 8192).

What `msgsz` are you using?

Comment: Thanks caf. I found that size of the pkt which i am using is almost 12000. It is the size of pkt which is causing me prblm. Can we change the value of MSGMAX?
Regards,
Bhavin.

Comment: That depends on the operating system.  On Linux, it can be changed system-wide with the `kernel.msgmax` sysctl (accessible at `/proc/sys/kernel/msgmax`).

Comment: Thanks caf i changed it by explicitly using that parameter in  /etc/sysctl.conf file and using sysctl -p.
Thanks again caf for your reply.
Regards,
Bhavin